# MY section in html is not hundred view height

Tags: html, css, height, display, viewport

HTML

<!-- Second section tag for about -->

```
\<section class="about" id="two"\>  

    \<div class="about-1"\>     

    \<img src="./Images/person.jpg" alt="" class="img-2"\>  

\</div\>            

       \<div class="about-2"\>  

    \<h2\>About \<span id="low"\>Me\</span\>\</h2\>         

\<h3 id="heading"\>Frontend Developer\</h3\>        

\<p\>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa eos iure sed similique quibusdam aspernatur doloremque commodi voluptate. Non est, eius ex, eveniet fugiat delectus repudiandae. Eius, doloremque dolores incidunt suscipit assumenda aliquam nemo dicta repellendus, in quaerat recusandae laboriosam natus. Cupiditate eum, asperiores quod nulla quae dolor perspiciatis aspernatur.\</p\>  

    \<a href="#" class="btn-1"\>Read More\</a\>
```

</div>

```
\</section\>
```

<!-- Third section tag for services -->

```
\<section class="services" id="three"\>     

\<h2 id="buy"\>Our \<span id="buy-1"\>Services\</span\>\</h2\>  

\<div class="services-1"\>\</div\>  \</section\>
```

CSS

```
.about{
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap: 100px;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 70px 120px 0 120px;
    background: #323946;
}
.img-2{
    max-width: 450px;
    height: 450px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border: 10px solid #0ef;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #0ef;
}
.about-2{
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}
h2{
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: -100px;
}
#low{
    color: var(--color1);
}
#heading{
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}
.btn-1{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: var(--color1);
    padding: 14px 28px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--color1);
    transition: .7s;
    font-weight: 600;
    
}
.services{
    height: 100vh;
}
```

My section tag is set to 100vh yet the contents of this section keep encroaching to the previous section
tag
I expected the about section to be 100vh and the services section to be 100vh but based on the background colour i used the services section was not up to 100vh.[image: Rendered website]

Comment: Your html has syntax errors the mdn docs will help.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics

Comment: why you everthing tag markup you give \ ?

Comment: Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/aussieworz83/o53g71dj/17/

Answer (score 0):

You should probably include:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

This will generalize the padding and margin to fit.
Next, you can set height to 100%.

Do let me know if it works.

Comment: bad if everthing tag can padding 0 and margin 0